# Yii2 jquery bubbling handling on ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

First: I don't know if my title is well constructed and i wan't to apologies for that! 
I have a modal form in which are shown messages sent from all the users. When i click on message it should open it via ajax request in the same form! The problem is that, when i click on some message, it seems there is bubbling occur. After refreshing the page and click again sometimes it bubbles to the last message, sometimes not. Not sure what is that behavior. Will bag you for some advice, because i am struggling whit it almost 1 day.. I want to just open the chosen message. I tried whit `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` but it is opening the first message every time.

my modal code:

```
<?php
                    Modal::begin([
                            'header' => '<h2><em>Messages</em></h2>',
                            'headerOptions' => [
                                    'class' => 'text-center',
                                ],
                            'id' => 'modal',
                            'size' => 'modal-md',
                    ]);

                    echo "<div id='userMessages' style='border: 1px solid black'>";
                        if(\app\controllers\UserController::getMessages())
                        {
                            $messages = \app\controllers\UserController::getMessages();

                            echo "<table class='table table-responsive'>
                                  <thead class='text-center thead-style'>
                                        <td>Title</td>
                                        <td>Author</td>
                                        <td>View</td>
                                  </thead>";

                            foreach ($messages as $message)
                            {
                                echo "<tr>

                                        <td class='text-center'>". $message['message_title'] ."</td>
                                        <td class='text-center'>". $message['message_author'] ."</td>
                                        <td class='text-center'>" . Html::a('<span class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open\'></span>',
                                                                                            ['#'],
                                                                                            ['class' => 'view-message']);
                                                                    $this->registerJs("$('.view-message').on('click', function(event){

                                                                        event.preventDefault();

                                                                        $.ajax({
                                                                            url : '". \yii\helpers\Url::to(["message", "id" => $message['message_id']]) ."',
                                                                            cache : false,
                                                                            success : function( data ){
                                                                                $('#userMessages').html( data );
                                                                            }       
                                                                        });
                                                                    })")
                                        . "</td>
                                      </tr>";
                            }

                            echo "</table>";
                        }
                    echo "</div>";

                    Modal::end();
                ?>
```

my actionMessage:

```
public function actionMessage($id)
    {
        $currMessage = UsersMessages::find()->where(['message_id' => $id])->one();

        return $this->renderAjax('message',[
            'msg' => $currMessage
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently adding multiple click events, so the first click event is triggered only, you need only one click event so remove the js from the loop and add a data attribute to your button with the message id, then add that id in the javascript and build your url

```
foreach ($messages as $message)
{
    echo "<tr>

            <td class='text-center'>". $message['message_title'] ."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>". $message['message_author'] ."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>" . Html::a('<span class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open\'></span>',
                                                                ['#'],
                                                                ['class' => 'view-message','data-id'=> $message['message_id']]);

            . "</td>
          </tr>";
}
$this->registerJs("$('.view-message').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        url : '". \yii\helpers\Url::to(["message"]) ."?id='+id,
        cache : false,
        success : function( data ){
            $('#userMessages').html( data );
        }       
    });
})")
```

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: Problem occur :) `jquery.js:9175 GET http://letsblog/user/message19?_=1491466863783 404 (Not Found)`. I tried to pass the id like an param in the `Url:to["message", "id" => 'id']` but without success :/ Can you give a little push again :)

Comment: try  `url : '". \yii\helpers\Url::to(["message"]) ."?id='+id,`

Comment: or  `url : '". \yii\helpers\Url::to(["message"]) ."/'+id,` i am not familiar with the yii route functions

Comment: Yes! Thank you a lot! I tried this way also but the problem was just a typo :) #userMessage in fact is #userMessages :) Thank you a lot again !